# Using dynamically assigned port in guest executable in Service Fabric

Tags: azure-service-fabric

From the a guest executable, a Rest Server, how I can get the port assigned by Service Fabric?

I need to configure my executable to use this port. I guess I could use the port number as a parameter to execute my app, but I have not found it.

A workaround is 
https://medium.com/@mattmazzola/service-fabric-using-dynamically-assigned-port-in-guest-executable-91a881e2a27a but it is not officially supported, so it could not work in a next version.

Answer (score 0):

Following environment variable should be set before the guest executable starts

Fabric_Endpoint_[YourServiceName]TypeEndpoint

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-fabric/service-fabric-manage-multiple-environment-app-configuration